# rpcinfo: couldn't find a suitable transport

Tags: nfs, rpcbind

After setting up NFS on a server, `rpcinfo -p servername` from a client is returning the error message

```
rpcinfo: couldn't find a suitable transport
```

Connectivity is fine, checked with `tcpdump`.
On the server `hosts.allow` contains the necessary entries. `/etc/netconfig` contains the following

```
# This config file is part of some non-installed packages (like nfs-utils)
#
# In case you install a tool that requires this file, please comment out the following lines:
#
# from https://highon.coffee/blog/security-harden-centos-7/
#
# udp6       tpi_clts      v     inet6    udp     -       -
# tcp6       tpi_cots_ord  v     inet6    tcp     -       -

udp        tpi_clts      v     inet     udp     -       -
tcp        tpi_cots_ord  v     inet     tcp     -       -
#udp6      tpi_clts      v     inet6    udp     -       -
#tcp6      tpi_cots_ord  v     inet6    tcp     -       -
rawip      tpi_raw       -     inet      -      -       -
local      tpi_cots_ord  -     loopback  -      -       -
unix       tpi_cots_ord  -     loopback  -      -       -
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The problem, believe it or not, was caused by the blank line after the main comment block in the file `/etc/netconfig`. After removing the blank line, the mount worked.